# ASP.Net / ASP.NET Core Web API unauthorized requests returns 302 redirect response instead of 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.Net / ASP.Net Core WebAPI,

When the client/browser tries to access a WebAPI endpoint which is decorated with **`[Authorized]`** attribute. It gets a **`302-Found`** status code with a redirect response to the Login page, instead of **`401-Unauthorized`** for an unauthorized request.

Note: I have noticed that **`Fail(AuthorizationContext context)`** method in **AuthorizeAttribute** filter sets the response code as **`401-Unauthorized`**, but eventually browser gets a **`302-Found`** response.

How can I send the **401** response instead of **302** ?

***UPDATE: Update the question with ASP.NET Core***

Comment: I think you might find the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149750/unauthorised-webapi-call-returning-login-page-rather-than-401
As this is not new to vNext.

Comment: @FrankWitte Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. In ASP.NET 5, AFAIK **`System.Web`** (`System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` or  `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`) is no longer used, instead `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` has the **AuthorizeAttribute**. And as I mentioned, it correctly sets 401 code in `Fail` method. And I found out that **Identity** middleware (`app.UseIdentity()`) turns the 401 code to 302. As a dirty solution I can put a middleware on top of Identity middleware and convert back to 401. but, still hoping for a better solution. Anyway thanks again. :)

Comment: [How to return 401 instead of 302 in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800919/how-to-return-401-instead-of-302-in-asp-net-core?rq=1) and [Disable Not Authorized Redirect to Account/Login in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455395/disable-not-authorized-redirect-to-account-login-in-asp-net-core?rq=1) may be useful. Accepted answer didn't work for me with Asp.Net Core 2.2. Answer in link 1 worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

The redirection happens with the **Cookie Authentication** module. By default its `LoginPath` property is set to `/Account/Login`. If it is set to `PathString.Empty`, it will keep the status code as `401-Unauthorized` without changing it to `302-Found`.

Change `CookieAuthenticationOptions` in **Startup.cs** as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other configurations ...

    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
    });

    // ...
}
```

XML documentation of `LoginPath` property:

> The LoginPath property informs the middleware that it should change an outgoing 401 Unauthorized status
>   code into a 302 redirection onto the given login path. The current url which generated the 401 is added
>   to the LoginPath as a query string parameter named by the ReturnUrlParameter. Once a request to the
>   LoginPath grants a new SignIn identity, the ReturnUrlParameter value is used to redirect the browser back
>   to the url which caused the original unauthorized status code.
>
> If the LoginPath is null or empty, the middleware will not look for 401 Unauthorized status codes, and it will
>   not redirect automatically when a login occurs.

---

**UPDATE:** As @swdon pointed out, **ASP.NET Core 2.x** has a different way of doing this.

Here's the accepted answer from the [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38800919/826611):

As of **ASP.NET Core 2.x**:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Comment: Your solution is not working in beta7. It still returns 302 and redirects to login. Did you manage to solve this in beta 7? There is AutomaticAuthentication property now also available, but when I set it to false, it says "The following authentication scheme was not accepted"

Comment: @Vitaly, set AutomaticChallenge = false and use AuthorizeAttribute with Schema parameter like this: [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "ApplicationCookie")]. You also should specify your schema in startup. Works in RC1-Final

Comment: But that would break mvc redirectino to login no?

Answer (score 0):

The answer the author provided works in case if you use identity authorization.
The problem is that identity approach spoiled by forcing you to use third party services and/or excessive for simple cases.
So, for my site I decided to use good old cookie authorization. In this case to have 401 for unauthorized requests you need:

```
       // Configure cookie based authentication
       builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {                
            // Specify the name of the auth cookie.
            // ASP.NET picks a dumb name by default.
            options.Cookie.Name = "my_app_auth_cookie";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")
                    && context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```