# ASP.NET core Web API Authorize Attribute return 404 Error & force redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have asp.net core 2.0 solution which contains following projects:

- Data: a class library for EF code
- OAuth: as web application project for IdentityServer4 code
- Api: for my API created as empty web project

Now the OAuth project is configured with aspnetidentity and its working fine, I able to get the token after authentication, and this is the startup code for it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // connect with normal database
    services.AddDbContext<MCareContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration
              .GetConnectionString("MCareConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MCareContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


    services.AddMvc();

    // IS configurations database
    var dbConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MCareConnection.OAuth");
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

    services.AddIdentityServer()
         .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
         {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
         })

        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })

        .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    DatabaseInitializer.InitializeDatabase(app);

    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Now the problem on the API project, whenever I open any authorized controller/action its give me 404 error, and this the startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MCareContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration
      .GetConnectionString("MCareConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MCareContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
     {
         options.Authority = "http://localhost:60415";
         options.ApiName = "mCareApi";
         options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();            

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

If I close this part on the above code:

```
//services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MCareContext>()
    //.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then the Authorize attribute work as expected, but another new problem, it shows 500 internal server error, whenever I opened any controller like AccountController which expect UserManager userManager on its constructor

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[MCare.Data.Entities.User]
>   while attempting to activate MCare.Api.Controllers.AccountsController

I want to know why this is happening and how to solve this problem, without mixing IdentityServer4 project with the API project, because all the projects I have seen they mix both of them on one project.

Comment: Why do you need AspNetIdentity in your RestAPI project?

Comment: Create account, reset password, and the other acccount management features

Comment: Please post your logs from the moment you start requesting an authorized route in your browser.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is it possible that DefaultChallengeScheme is redirecting to a page that does not exist such as a login page when it encounters the authorize attribute which could cause the 404?

Try setting the default challenge to the Jwt schema which returns not authorized.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:60415";
    options.ApiName = "mCareApi";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

Or you could try the method I mentioned in the article below by providing a handler for the event.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:60415";
    options.ApiName = "mCareApi";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, But I don't want this redirection to happen because its Web Api and its doesn't have login page, I expect to return 401 UnAuthorized status code from that controller.

Comment: Prior to Core 2.0, there was a property to turn off AutoChallenge.  In 2.0 Ithink you need to override the AutoChallenge by adding your own code in the event for OnRedirectToLogin in the options.  Let me see if I can find that article somewhere...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878166/asp-net-core-2-0-disable-automatic-challenge

Comment: The solution is to explicit set both default authentication and challenge schema as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to add the AddAuthentication line after the AddControllers() line