# RedirectToLogin handler not called when a role is not fulfilled (cookie authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, cookie-authentication

I have a ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) API controller that makes sure that only authenticated users can access its endpoints using the `Authorize` attribute:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/borrower")]
public class BorrowerController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

Since it serves a REST API, instead of returning 302 redirect responses, I prefer having 401 unautherized responses so I've configured my cookie authentication in `Startup`:

```
services.AddScoped<CookieAuthenticationEventsHandler>();
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    ...
    o.EventsType = typeof(CookieAuthenticationEventsHandler);
})
```

and:

```
public class CookieAuthenticationEventsHandler : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Works as expected. Instead of 302, I get a 401 on unauthenticated requests.

What does **not** work is when I introduce roles-based access control and I change the above `[Authorize]` to `[Authorize(Roles = "Borrower")]` for example.

A request to the controller with a principal that *is* authenticated but does *not* assume that role again results in a 302 instead of 401. Setting a breakpoint in the `RedirectToLogin` method shows that in this case the method is not being called (i.e. the event is not raised).

Also, I don't see any other event that would be suitable for this scenario.

Is this by design or is it a bug? Am I missing something here? And how could I still turn that 302 into a 401.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to have a 403 Forbidden in the case of a missing role for an API end-point instead of a 302.

Comment: Pls show your middleware order for me in Startup.cs. I want check `Authentication`  and `Authorization` 's order. `Authentication` should always be placed before `Authorization`.

Comment: @JasonPan I've check that and the order is fine.

Comment: Your code about `services.AddScoped<CookieAuthenticationEventsHandler>();
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`, seems like registing as service, it will run when your application start. I suggest you create a middleware to handle this issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646693/7687666