# Role based authorization policy does not work

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I currently have ASP.NET Core Web API back-end. I'm using react google login, it works fine. Now I want to implement role-based authorization to authorize some back-end api.
When I use`[Authorize]`, it works fine.
But I use `[Authorize(Policy = "readpolicy")]`, it can not hit the method.
I tried lots of approaches together, therefore the `Program.cs` looks terrible. Below What I tried, :

The entire `Program.cs`, anyone knows and how to fix the problem? Even help me to reorganize the code what I need and don't need and I'm not sure that the sequence of these services functions is correct.

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WTSS_Portal_Middleware.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
}
);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TSTWTSSPortalContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("UserDbConnection")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "WTSS_Portal_Middleware", Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddJwtBearer()
        .AddCookie()
        ;
builder.Services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("readpolicy",
        policy => policy.RequireRole("WTSS support", "System owner", "Regular user", "Company owner", "Unauthenticated"));
    options.AddPolicy("writepolicy",
        policy => policy.RequireRole("WTSS support", "System owner"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WTSS_Portal_Middleware V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

assign role to logged in user

```html
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, payload.Name),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Regular user") //default role
    }, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

Comment: Add `RequireAuthenticatedUser` to your policies: `policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(...).RequireRole(...)`

Comment: @abdusco thx for quick reply, but it still does not work

Comment: What do the logs say? Increase the log level for `Microsoft.AspNetCore` to `Information` and check for auth logs.

Comment: @abdusco I don't know log at high level. I have ILogger inside method, but it can't be hit. I can only check the browser f12 Network, it says 403 Forbidden.

Comment: It's not about your log usages. Asp.Net logs why a request isn't dispatched to your action. Change the log level in appsettings.$env.json and watch server logs.

Comment: @abdusco i think this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329756/authorize-policy-always-return-403-forbidden-mvc-api  Still not working, and I just changed the business logic, I'm away from ASP.NET Core Identity because I already retrieve access token and based on it I can get all related data like role