# ASP.NET Core Authentication, controller-based response type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1 web application has normal controllers (that return HTML pages) and web-api controllers in the same project.

I implemented authentication and authorization mechanisms with Identity framework and cookies.

At the moment, the application redirects the anonymous users to the login page when they try to access a controller with [Authorize] annotation.

This behaviour is reasonable for view-controllers, but I want to return a status code in case of web-api controllers (for requests that start with /api). How can I achieve this?

I've found some answers about this, but related on version 1.0 of ASP.NET Core, and not suitable for 2.1.

Many thanks.

Comment: are you using the right Authorize annotation for web api? There should be one under web api namespace and one under mvc namespace.

Comment: How are you calling your WebAPI from the site? REST methods?

Comment: I've found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800919/how-to-return-401-instead-of-302-in-asp-net-core).  Thanks for help.