# .net core 2.1 [ApiController] return 401 instead of 302

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core

Should the new (ish) [ApiController] attribute in .net core 2.1 return a 401 response rather than a 302 for unauthorized requests?

I cant find any documentation but would seem logical to me, but on testing it seems to still return a 302. If not, could it, or why would this not be a good idea and does that mean i still need to do something funky in my OnRedirectToLogin as explored here [How to return 401 instead of 302 in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800919/how-to-return-401-instead-of-302-in-asp-net-core)

My project is an SPA so has a single MVC controller serving the application and then a series of API controllers. I am using CookieAuthentication which may be where the issue lies. Is there a way to do Cookie Authentication for the MVC which serves the SPA and then another Authentication scheme maybe validating Bearer token for the API Controllers without separating out to a separate project?

Many thanks, Ed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return 401 instead of 302 in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800919/how-to-return-401-instead-of-302-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: hmm yes similar for sure, i think there are two parts to this, one is that i shouldnt be using cookie auth for my api anyway, seems as if i use JWT for the api controllers they will behave correctly anyway, looks like i can do that using ForwardDefaultSelector in OpenIdConnect middleware as explained here https://leastprivilege.com/2018/06/14/mixing-ui-and-api-endpoints-in-asp-net-core-2-1-aka-dynamic-scheme-selection/