# Disable Not Authorized Redirect to Account/Login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have a set of WebAPI services in a shared library.  These are used in an ASP.NET Core MVC Web Site and dedicated server only hosting the WebAPI Services without the MVC component.

Everything works as expected on the MVC Web Site with Unauthorized Requests, I get the 304 redirect to the login page (Account/Login). However when I make an unauthorized request to the WebAPI services, I receive the same 304 redirect to /Account/Login in this case I would like to return the Http 401 Unauthorized result code.  I would prefer to not handle this in a custom AuthorizeAttribute but would rather handle at the site level in my Startup class.

Comment: That's because you have registered the cookie middleware for both, WebAPI and your MVC View part of the page. Can you post your configure method to confirm it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you have registered ASP.NET Core Identity with both your MVC (Views) Part as well as with your WebApi part.

You must separate it and the CookieMiddleware (one registered inside `.UseIdentity()` call) must only be registered for request to your MVC pages, but not for your WebAPI calls.

You can use the `.Map` or `MapWhen` methods (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)).

```
// For requests not going to WebAPI controllers
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), branch =>
{
    branch.UseIdentity();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tseng, I had still planned on using the ASP.NET Core Identity Functionality in my WebApi server.  I just don't want the redirect.  This seems like this should be possible, am I missing something?  I believe in Pre-ASP.NET Core version you could do this with the flag "SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedi‌​rect" on the Response.  This does not seem to be present in the ASP.NET Core

Comment: Well you can register the cookie middleware manually on ASP.NET Core WebApi path with `AutomaticAuthenticate ` set to `false`, because the ASP.NET Core Identity MIddleware registers multiple CookieAuthentications (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L36-L39) and it's default is automatically authenticate (https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L27). that's what's causing the redirect

Comment: That eliminated the redirect, however with that, it is no longer looking for any sort of token.  My goal is to pass the token as part of the authorization header rather than a cookie, and still use ASP.NET Identity.  That's a different question however.

Comment: Which Schema did you register it for? Identity registers 4 schemes. I think the ApplicationCookie should be the right one. Dunno what kind of token you are speaking with, but when you use cookie authorization the cookie will be read by the middleware, no need to pass any tokens. Bearer Token/JWT is a different authorization type

Comment: My Web App/MVC Razor uses Cookies my WebAPI server uses JWT.