# Why I can't get into POST processing part of controller in ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I sent data from database to view and showed them in drop-down list. After picking some item I got empty webpage instead of id of picked item along with drop-down list. I discovered that after picking, processing is not continuing in [HttpPost] part of controller.

Here is my controller:

```
namespace AssetServer.Controllers
{
    public class AssetsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AssetContext _context;

        public AssetsController(AssetContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Assets
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<Asset> AssetsTableList = new List<Asset>();
            AssetsTableList = await _context.Assets.OrderBy(p => p.Ticker).ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.AssetsTableList = AssetsTableList.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Ticker, Value = m.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Asset Asset)
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedValue = Asset.Id;

            List<Asset> AssetsTableList = new List<Asset>();
            AssetsTableList = await _context.Assets.OrderBy(p => p.Ticker).ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.AssetsTableList = AssetsTableList.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.Ticker, Value = m.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And whole view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AssetServer.Domain.Assets.Asset>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Assets", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.DropDownList("Title", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AssetsTableList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
   @ViewBag.SelectedValue;
}
```

Debugging in Chrome show "500 Internal Server Error":

[image]

EDIT:

My routes:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute( 
                name: "default", 
                template: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                constraints: new { controller = @"^(?:(?!contact|.well-known|api).)*$" }
                ); 

            /* WebAPI routes set with attributes */

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback", 
                constraints: new { controller = @"^(?:(?!contact|.well-known|api).)*$" },
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
        });
```

Comment: Did you validated this?

Comment: @Tseng Nope. As far as I know validation is performed at the beginning of [HttpPost] part, but program flow didn't get there at all.

Comment: I mean with a break point. If it doesn't  hit your action, then something is wrong with your routing, which we can't tell since we don't see your routes.

Comment: @Tseng
Yes! With break point.

Routing - that's what I suspected. I added EDIT with my routes.
Thanks!

Comment: Any exceptions in the log (add "loggerFactory.AddDebug()" if you don't have already, then logs will be shown in Visual Studio debug output)?

Comment: @Tseng
This is from beginning part of the log after I chose item:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/Assets application/x-www-form-urlencoded 192
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.Infrastructure.NopAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No token found.
...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Error: Connection id "0HL4ATIIFFAA1": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
...`

Comment: You have misconfigured your WebAPI then. You can use bearer token only, when you use ajax, because you have to set the `Authorization` header, (i.e. `Authorization: bearer abc123`). You must configure that middleware only for the /api path, but not for your other routes

Comment: Also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455395/disable-not-authorized-redirect-to-account-login-in-asp-net-core/43456151#43456151) for how do request branching in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Thanks.
As far as I understood this is code I need to put in my startup.cs file:
`app.MapWhen(ap => ap.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), branch =>
{
    branch.UseIdentity();
});`
After putting it in place of `app.UseIdentity();` I got blank webpage instead my homepage.

Comment: Debug output shows:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Error: Connection id "0HL4B06DTV1ON": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Identity.Application
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<GetAuthenticateInfoAsync>d__11.MoveNext()`

Comment: @Tseng
The goal for now is to make this code working, i.e. process POST in any way, just to continue developing.
I think that authorization will be needed afterwards for this part also, as well as for WebAPI.

Comment: @Tseng
By the way if I return my application to state before adding new controller and view, in debug output I'm getting the same warning, but whole application is working well it seems:
`IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.Infrastructure.NopAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No token found.`