# .net-core middleware return blank result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

Im making a website with an API, the API needs validation so the user only gets his own data. I have written the following middleware to validate the login.

```
public class ApiAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public ApiAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> usermanager)
    {
        _next = next;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = usermanager;
    }

    public async  Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("password") || !context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("email"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User Key");
            return;
        }
        var email = context.Request.Query["email"];
        var password = context.Request.Query["password"];

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        else if (//some more checks)
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User Key");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that a blank page or an error message like "Invalid User Key" is shown if the user has no valid login. However what happens at the moment is the home page is returned (because my middleware is called before usemvc and the return statement skips the controller request done by usemvc).

My relevant code in the configure method in startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseWhen(x => (x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
            builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMiddleware<ApiAuthenticationMiddleware>();
            });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

How can I make my middleware return a blank page with status code?

**Update**

After trying alot of things I found that when I remove:

```
 context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
```

It works as expected, the user gets the message given in:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User Key");
```

Howerver I dont want the user to get a 200 statuscode on login fail but a 401 statuscode. But when using the statuscode line the user is redirected. So how can I send the statuscode without redirection?

Comment: Why not using `Authorize` attribute

Comment: Authorize assumes a user is logged in (via cookie if im correct) Im making an API for a mobile app so the app sends requests which needs to be from a valid user. Also authorize will redirect to the register page if not loggedin which is not the behaviour I want for my API.

Comment: I would take a look at the OpenId Middleware. This Middleware works with the Authorize Attribute

Comment: @ChristianSauer Thanks Christian I will, but I would still like to know how I can solve the current problem.

Comment: What Version of NetCore is this?
My middleware looks different then yours (e.g. it's a class)
See https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/writing-custom-middleware-in-asp-net-core-1-0/

Comment: @ChristianSauer Your link is exactly what I have, the link you posted explains how middleware works and when the " public async  Task Invoke()" method is called. added the full class decleration to avoid confusion though.

Comment: Thanks!
You could probably throw an exception, but I'm unsure it thats ok for your design.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, How is your application hosted? IIS? Kestrel?

Comment: @haim770 currently I am localy developing with IIS

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, Then it's probably the configuration in your `Web.config` that is automatically redirecting upon receiving "401 Unauthorized" response. Check your `<httpErrors>` and `<customErrors>` section.

Comment: Passing credentials in every request sounds like a bad idea. I'm no expert, but should use cookie authentication or something like OAuth2 where a short lived key is passed instead. Have you tried setting the `ContentType` header in the response object?

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart Does your Startup.cs contain something similar to `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");`.  
I had a similar problem that resulted in 4xx and 5xx status codes getting redirected to a controller action, because of this line.

Comment: What @BrandonK mentions is important too.  Sending credentials repeatedly isn't a good idea. Also, sending sensitive information (e.g. a password) via a query string is a bad practice too.  IIS by default logs the url, including query strings, so all of your users' passwords would be stored in plain text in a log file on your server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a hunch that `app.UseIdentity()` has default behavoir that when a 403/401 occurs, it will intercept the response and initiate a redirect. Try commenting it out and see if it works.

Alternate solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43456151/3948882

Last comment: I strongly encourage not passing credentials for each request. I recommend using prebuilt auth providers and implement as your middleware. The `Authorize` attribute should be sufficient for requests made and can do what you are looking for. If you do want to return something special, you can override the response with middleware like the `app.UseIdentity()` middleware might be with redirecting.

Answer (score 24):

Try to use .Clear() before setting the StatusCode .

```
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also set ContentType.
Something like this:

```
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User Key");
```